# How to compile all tests across a repo without executing them

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-build

I have a repo in which multiple teams contribute integration tests.

All these tests are hidden behind `//go:build integration` flags, so if I want `go` to see or run them, I need to pass the `-build integration` flag to the test command.

What I’m trying to accomplish is to compile all tests across the entirety of this repo without actually executing them (would take a long time) so I can catch build errors introduced by PRs that the default `go test` compilation and execution would not catch.

I see the `-c` flag:

> -c
> Compile the test binary to pkg.test but do not run it
> (where pkg is the last element of the package's import path).
> The file name can be changed with the -o flag.

However… one cannot use the `-c` flag with the `-build` flag:

> $ go test -build=integration -c ./integrationtests/client/admin-api
>
> go: unknown flag -build=integration cannot be used with -c

Also... one cannot use the `-c` flag across multiple packages:

> $ go test -c ./...
>
> cannot use -c flag with multiple packages

Any ideas?

Comment: "**so I can catch build errors introduced by PRs that the default go test compilation and execution would not catch.**" How would you execute the tests without building them?

Comment: Sorry - some clarification. By "the default go test execution," I mean `go test ./...`. That test execution would not build (nor run) any tests that have build flags. You can have a compiler error in a test file that has a build flag and `go test ./...` will not throw an error like you would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `go test -run` flag and pass it a pattern you know will never match:

```
go test -run=XXX_SHOULD_NEVER_MATCH_XXX ./...

ok      mypkg       0.731s [no tests to run]
```

this will catch any test compilation errors - and if there are none - no tests will be run.

If you need to pass any build tags that are typically passed during your `go build` process (e.g. `go build -tags mytag`), you can do the same during `go test`:

```
go test -tags mytag -run=XXX_SHOULD_NEVER_MATCH_XXX ./...
```

---

Full details on the `-run` flag from the inline (`go help testflag`) docs:

```
        -run regexp
            Run only those tests, examples, and fuzz tests matching the regular
            expression. For tests, the regular expression is split by unbracketed
            slash (/) characters into a sequence of regular expressions, and each
            part of a tests identifier must match the corresponding element in
            the sequence, if any. Note that possible parents of matches are
            run too, so that -run=X/Y matches and runs and reports the result
            of all tests matching X, even those without sub-tests matching Y,
            because it must run them to look for those sub-tests.
```

Comment: Cool idea! I couldn't get `go test -build integration -run ASDFASDF ./...` to work though. That one doesn't catch a compiler error I introduced in a test file. `build constraints exclude all Go files`

Comment: Turns out I can just use `-tags integration` instead of `-build integration` and this works great!

Comment: updated answer to include the `-tags` note.

Comment: I am seeing this approach taking a really long time when I include this command as part of a jenkins job and multiple builds of that job get triggered on the jenkins node.

is this expected? At times (with the parallel jobs) the command takes almost 30-35 minutes for a really small repository.